# Equation + explanation below

Tags: tables, math-mode, equations, amsmath

I have to write an explanation to my equation, and I would like to do it, below the equation. But, I do not know how to do that.

It should look like this:
[image]

My preamble look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc} 
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx,multirow,tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
E = \alpha X + \beta F + u
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you want, I would recommend using a list type environment such as `itemize` from [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem), along with [the `varwidth`  package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/varwidth):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc} 
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx,multirow,tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm,mathtools}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
E = \alpha X + \beta F + u
\end{equation}
\begin{center}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
    \item [$E$] is xxx
    \item [$X$] is yyy
\end{itemize}
\end{varwidth}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```